# "error while accessing backend services for API key validation" using wso2apim with mysql

Tags: wso2

I want to use multiple instances of wso2apim using the same mysql DB.
First im trying to configure a single instance with mysql database following this article:
https://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager

I have managed to get all the webapps running.
- Created a new API using publisher.
- Singned up a new subscriber on the store.
- Logged in to the store as subscriber
- Subscribbed to the API and generated the access token.

But when I try to access this API I get an error 900900 `Unclassified Authentication Failure - Error while accessing backend services for API key validation`

Here are some of my configuration files

**master-datascources.xml**

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for the API Manager database</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://apimgtdb.mysql-wso2.com:3306/apimgtdb?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true</url>
            <username>root</username>
            <password>mypassword</password>
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>

<datasource>
    <name>WSO2UM_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used by user manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://userdb.mysql-wso2.com:3306/userdb?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true</url>
            <username>root</username>
            <password>mypassword</password>
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>

<datasource>
    <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used by user manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://regdb.mysql-wso2.com:3306/regdb?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true</url>
            <username>root</username>
            <password>mypassword</password>
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

**api-manager.xml**

```
<AuthManager>
        <ServerURL>https://keymanager.apim-wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>admin</Password>
    </AuthManager>

    <APIGateway>

    <Environments>
        <Environment type="hybrid">
                <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
                <ServerURL>https://gwmanager.apim-wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL>
                <Username>admin</Username>
                <Password>admin</Password>
                <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
        </Environment>
    </Environments>

    <APIKeyManager>
        <ServerURL>https://keymanager.apim-wso2.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>admin</Password>
        .
        .
    </APIKeyManager>
```

**registry.xml**

```
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
<enableCache>true</enableCache>
<registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>


<dbConfig name="govregistry">
  <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://publisher.apim-wso2.com"> 
   <id>gov</id>
   <cacheId>user@jdbc:mysql://regdb.mysql-wso2.com:3306/regdb</cacheId>
   <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
   <readOnly>false</readOnly>
   <enableCache>true</enableCache>
   <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>

.
.
.
.
```

**user-mgt.xml**

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
                <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>admin</UserName>
                     <Password>admin</Password>
                </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</Property>
            <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
            <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>

        <AuthorizationManager
            class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
    </UserManager>
```

I have also noticed that even after doing this, on the carbon home page the DBMS is still shown as "H2". Is this something that has to do with this error??

[image]

Comment: I just saw this   https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1353  Maybe that will help